# How to show the Hamiltonian is conserved

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamilton-equations

I have the langrangian $L = \frac 1 2m((1+4r^2)r’^2) + \frac 1 2 mr^2 θ’^2 -mgr^2  $

I worked out theHamiltonian and 4 Hamiltonian equations and got

$\frac {dpθ}{dt} = 0 $ for one of them $pθ$ is the momentum of the angle

Is that enough to show that the Hamiltonian is conserved.

Comment: What exactly do you want to show? The Hamiltonian is always preserved in a Hamiltonian system. That the Lagrangian does not depend on the angle directly implies from the Euler-Laplace equations that the angular momentum is preserved, this is a second constant of this system.

Comment: I need to show explicitly the hamiltonian is conserved. I know it will be conserved but I'm not sure how show it

Comment: @LutzLehmann In general $\frac{dH}{dt}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}$ need not be zero.

Comment: @J.G. : Yes, that may be the case. However here there is no explicit time dependence in the Lagrangian and thus also not in the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Hence my "in general", against your "always preserved in a Hamiltonian system".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Euler-Lagrange equations with momentum variables, you get
$\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}$
\begin{align}
p_r&=\pd{L}{\dot r}=m(1+r^2)\dot r\\
p_θ&=\pd{L}{\dot θ}=mr^2\dot θ
\end{align}
and then
\begin{align}
\dot p_r&=\pd{L}{r}=4mr\dot r^2+mr\dot θ^2-2mgr\\
\dot p_θ&=\pd{L}{θ}=0
\end{align}
For the Hamiltonian you should get
$$
H=p_r\dot r+p_θ\dot θ-L=\frac{p_r^2}{2m(1+4r^2)}+\frac{p_θ^2}{2mr^2}+mgr^2.
$$
It is now easy to check that $\dot q=H_p$ and $\dot p=-H_q$ gives the same equations as the Euler-Lagrange formalism, so that indeed $\dot H=H_p\dot p+H_q\dot q=0$.